# Not able to get Highlight & Count VBA working

Tags: vba, excel

I found a macro to count & Highlight Duplicates. My friend & I have tried to get it working, but have not been able to get it working. Column A  ( Name), Column L ( Yes - Filter), Column M (Duplicate).  In addition to getting the code working, we are trying to get the macro to filter on Yes in column L, and Print **Duplicate** in Column M. Please advise what is wrong & how to fix the problem. Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Find_Duplicates()

Dim col As Integer
Dim rng As String
col = 3
rng = "A5:A"
HighLightDuplicates rng, col
ShowMaxOnly rng, col

End Sub

Sub HighLightDuplicates(ByVal rng As String, ByVal col As Integer)
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim temp As Variant
Range(rng).Select
Dim Count As Integer
Count = 1

 For i = 1 To Selection.Count
   temp = Range(Left(rng, 1) & i)
   For j = i + 1 To Selection.Count
     If temp = Range(Left(rng, 1) & j) And temp <> "" Then
         Count = Count + 1 'increase the number of duplicates
         'highlight the duplicates
         Range(Left(rng, 1) & i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 100, 255)
         Range(Left(rng, 1) & j).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 100, 255)
     End If
   Next
   'show the number of duplicates
   If Count > 1 Then
     Cells(i, col) = Count & " duplicates"
   End If
   'reset count
   Count = 1
 Next
 End Sub
 'show only the biggest number of duplicates in a group


 Sub ShowMaxOnly(ByVal rng As String, ByVal col As Integer)
 Dim i, j As Integer
 Dim temp As Variant
 Range(rng).Select

   i = 1
   For i = 1 To Selection.Count
     temp = Range(Left(rng, 1) & i)
     For j = i + 1 To Selection.Count
      If temp = Range(Left(rng, 1) & j) And temp <> "" Then
         Cells(j, col) = "" 'remove the smaller numbers duplicates
      End If
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Check `rng = "A5:A"`. AFAIK, this isnt a valid range.

Comment: A is the column for the name. What is the best way of making the range the entire column, starting with cell 5?

Comment: Maybe `A:A` or `A5:A10` or whatever range you actually need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would work for you.

It adds the formula and then uses conditional formatting to highlight the cells.

```
Public Sub Find_Duplicates()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet 'The worksheet that you're lookin for duplicates in.
    Dim rng As Range        'The range containing the duplicates.
    Dim Col As Long         'The last column containing data +1

    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With wrkSht
        'Reference to whole data range.
        Set rng = .Range("A5:L25")

        'If the sheet is blank an error will be thrown when trying to find the last column.
        'This code looks for the last column - you could just set Col to equal the last column number + 1.
        On Error Resume Next
            Col = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
            Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Col = 0 Then Col = 1

        'Place a COUNTIF formula in the last column.
        rng.Offset(, Col).Columns(1).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(" & rng.Columns(1).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",RC" & rng.Column & ") & "" duplicates."""

        With rng
            'Add conditional formatting to first column in range: If the COUNTIF formula is showing >1 then highlight cell.
            With .Columns(1)
                'This formula is =VALUE(LEFT($M5,FIND(" ",$M5)-1))>1.
                'It returns only the number from the duplicate count and checks it is higher than 1.
                .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
                    "=VALUE(LEFT(" & rng.Offset(, Col).Cells(1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False) & ",FIND("" ""," & _
                    rng.Offset(, Col).Cells(1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False) & ")-1))>1"
                .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
                .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 100, 255)
            End With

            'Apply filter to your range.
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="Yes"
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

**Updated code:**
This will always place the last column as 1 to the right of the range set in the variable `rng`.

```
Public Sub Find_Duplicates()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet 'The worksheet that you're lookin for duplicates in.
    Dim rng As Range        'The range containing the duplicates.
    Dim rLastCol            '1 column to right of rng.
    Dim Col As Long         'The last column containing data +1

    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With wrkSht
        'Reference to whole data range.
        Set rng = .Range("A5:L25")
        Set rLastCol = rng.Offset(, 1).Columns(rng.Columns.Count)

        'Place a COUNTIF formula in the last column.
        rLastCol.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(" & rng.Columns(1).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",RC" & rng.Column & ") & "" duplicates."""

        With rng
            'Add conditional formatting to first column in range: If the COUNTIF formula is showing >1 then highlight cell.
            With .Columns(1)
                'This formula is =VALUE(LEFT($M5,FIND(" ",$M5)-1))>1.
                'It returns only the number from the duplicate count and checks it is higher than 1.
                .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
                    "=VALUE(LEFT(" & rLastCol.Cells(1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False) & ",FIND("" ""," & _
                    rLastCol.Cells(1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False) & ")-1))>1"
                .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
                .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 100, 255)
            End With

        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It works for a brief second & I see the results. Then all the data between  rows 5 & 2004 disappear. The only changes I made were to the sheet name from **Sheet1** to **Walk INs** &  the Range from **A5:L25** to **A5:L2003** Any idea what happened?

Comment: Does column L (12th column in the selected range - `Field:=12`) have 'Yes' in it?

Comment: The first time I ran it, it did not, when I had a Yes in column L, it did show a duplicate. However the data from row 5 to 2003 is gone. The only thing that is on the screen is row 1-4 & 2004 - 65000.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. _'The first time I ran it, it did not, when I had a Yes in column L, it did show a duplicate.'_  When you say the data in rows 5:2003 is gone - do you mean they're hidden by the filter, or they're completely gone?  If hidden by the filter - what's the filter set to?

Comment: Visually there is no data, and I am not able to scroll up. The first row after row 4 is row 2004.

Comment: If the row numbers jump from 4 to 2004 then it's filtered - the data is just hidden.  Row 4 should have little drop-down arrows on the right of the cells.  In 2010 column L should have a little filter icon next to the down arrow, in 2003 the down arrow will be coloured blue (hard to spot).  In 2010 clicking the arrow will show you a list of unique values in that column with a tick next to the one that's filtered, in 2003 the drop-down list will have highlighted the selected filter.  Is this anything like what you have?

Comment: LOL I totally forgot about the filter.  Is it possible to have the filter turned off, so I don't have to go through that step every time?  It also adds a column every time it is run. Can it show just the true duplicates in **column M**?

Comment: To remove the filter bit, just comment out or remove the two lines that start `.AutoFilter`. To set the last column manually to column M change this line: `Col = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column` to `Col = 13` (you can remove the rest of that block of code as well).

Comment: I removed the line of code & it still is adding a column. Did I miss something? ` On Error Resume Next
            Col = 13
            Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Col = 0 Then Col = 1`

Comment: I've added another block of code so the last column is always 1 to the right of your defined range - so `A5:L25` will always be `M5:M25`.

Comment: Did I miss something?  Should I change A5:L25 to M5:M25?